# CS0433: The type 'X' exists in both 'A' and 'B' - Clear Temporary ASP.NET Files from Azure AppService as part of Azure Devops release pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

When I try to reach for the site I'm getting the error on the title. Web Application project running on an App Services on Azure. Being deployed through Azure Devops.

When On premises I used to manually delete the Temporary ASP.NET Files and the site would recompile and this problem would no longer occurr. But now I'm trying to create a release pipeline on Azure Devops and reaching this error, so if I had in fact to clear those files every deploy, then it shoul be a part of my pipepline. Is this the correct approach? If so, how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure yet on how to clear the temporary asp.net files, but I could bypass the problem by adding the following line to the web.config:

```
<compilation batch="false"...
```